# Последовательное выполнение кода

Tags: javascript, jquery

Подскажите пожалуйста как последовательно выполнить эти 4 функции?

```js
setTimeout(function() {
        $('#div4').replaceWith("_");
        $('#div3').replaceWith("4");
        $('#div2').replaceWith("3");
        $('#div1').replaceWith("2");
    }, 5000);
    
setTimeout(function() {
        $('#div4').replaceWith("_");
        $('#div3').replaceWith("_");
        $('#div2').replaceWith("4");
        $('#div1').replaceWith("3");
}, 5000);

setTimeout(function() {
        $('#div4').replaceWith("_");
        $('#div3').replaceWith("_");
        $('#div2').replaceWith("_");
        $('#div1').replaceWith("4");
}, 5000);

setTimeout(function() {
        $('#div4').replaceWith("_");
        $('#div3').replaceWith("_");
        $('#div2').replaceWith("_");
        $('#div1').replaceWith("_");
}, 5000);
```

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: последовательно с промежутком в 5 секунд???

Comment: Да я хочу чтоб это все выполнялось с последовательностью в 5 секунд

Comment: Вы точно уверены, что вам нужен метод [`replaceWith`](https://api.jquery.com/replacewith/)? Он ведь заменит элементы на текст в первом же колбеке, и следующим колбекам уже негде будет что-то заменять.

Comment: нет, вообще задача заключатся в том, чтоб переставлять все цыфры на единицу влево каждые 5 сек , а это костыль, который я попытался сварганить , в силу плохого владения js-ом

Answer (score 3):

Можно так

```js
let time = 0;

setTimeout(function() {
  $('#div4').text("_");
  $('#div3').text("4");
  $('#div2').text("3");
  $('#div1').text("2");
}, time += 5000);

setTimeout(function() {
  $('#div4').text("_");
  $('#div3').text("_");
  $('#div2').text("4");
  $('#div1').text("3");
}, time += 5000);

setTimeout(function() {
  $('#div4').text("_");
  $('#div3').text("_");
  $('#div2').text("_");
  $('#div1').text("4");
}, time += 5000);

setTimeout(function() {
  $('#div4').text("_");
  $('#div3').text("_");
  $('#div2').text("_");
  $('#div1').text("_");
}, time += 5000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="div4">4</div>
<div id="div3">3</div>
<div id="div2">2</div>
<div id="div1">1</div>
```

Comment: Останавливается на первом(

Comment: @Mikhail всё работает с промежутком 5 секунд, сначала ждёт 5, потом 10, потом 15, потом 20 секунд

Comment: @Mikhail, все работает.

Comment: @Egettl, подскажи пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема? Как бы не старался, код дальше 1 функции не идет

Comment: Возможно остановка после первого раза, потому что код заменяет элементы текстовыми узлами и второй и последующие разы не находят уже элементы с нужными id.

Comment: @vsemozhebuty а как этого избежать?

Comment: Я, к сожалению, почти не знаю jQuery. Думаю, вам нужно искать функцию, которая заменяет текстовое содержимое элемента, а не заменяет сам элемент. Что-то вроде аналогов свойства `.textContent`. Попробуйте, например, [`.text( text )`](https://api.jquery.com/text/#text-text).

Comment: Я осмелился заменить этот метод в примере и добавить разметку, проверьте, работает ли сейчас так, как вам нужно.

Comment: @vsemozhebuty благодарю